# Getx controller cant dispose

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-get

i create a function to cek user, from API to check user login or not. i use this because my API is not realtime.
this my code for funcheckuser

```
void funfetchUser() async {
  print('get user');
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var token = prefs.getString('token');
  try {
    var headers = {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    };
    var url = Uri.parse(Api.base + Api.user);
    https.Response response = await https.get(url, headers: headers);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var user = jsonDecode(response.body)['user'];
      var isLogin = token;
      print(isLogin);
      UserList.email = user['email'];
      UserList.userlongname = user['user_longname'];
      UserList.userphone = user['user_phone'];
      
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), (() {
        if (isLogin == null) {
          Get.toNamed('/login');
        } else {
          print('stay');
        }
      }));
      
    } else {
      var login2 = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(login2);
      // customAllertDialog("Sesi", 'Sesi Berakhir', 'error');
      print('logout');
      prefs.clear();
      Get.toNamed('/login');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    prefs.clear();
  }
}
```

I create this fun on to all my controller

```
@override
  void onInit() {
    // TODO: implement onInit
    super.onInit();
    print('ini profile');
    funfetchUser();
  }
  @override
  void onReady() {
    // TODO: implement onReady
    super.onReady();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 
    30), (timer) { 
      print('cek user profile gan');
      funfetchUser();
    });
  }
  @override
  void onClose() {
    // TODO: implement onClose
    super.onClose();
    Get.delete<ProfilController>();
  }
```

that controller always run even i move page.
i want to call every controller in every page but the one n only controller run is contoller profile

Comment: As you are using Get.to to navigate to login, your controller stays alive. So, to dispose the controller go to login screen using Get.off. That way your controller will be disposed.

Answer (score 0):

The **removal** or **not** of the controllers in the `Getx` package is related to **routing**

And you should not delete controllers **manually**

Comment: i allready dellet manually but still can run. i dellet it in funfetchuser n logout